# I need to create a windows form from within a NUnit test

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit

I need to make a NUnit test class that tests my screen scraper.

1) I would like to have a [SetUp] method that will create a dummy window, simple windows form with just a predefined title and a background image. Setup method then should wait for a full initialization of the dummy window, i.e. wait for the dummy form to load and display background image and keep it open.

2) I will run the actual tests.

3) TearDown method will close the dummy window.

The 2) and 3) is not a problem (I think), but how would I do the 1), especially pass the control to the tests while keeping the dummy window open?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a form and show it modeless:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    m_myForm = new MyTestForm();
    m_myForm.Show(null);
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    m_myForm.Close();
    m_myForm.Dispose();
}
[Test]
//... some tests using the member variable
```